# Viewsonic Viewpad 10s not recognised by PC (over USB)

Tags: android, windows, eclipse, debugging

I'm about to start writing some Android applications, I have downloaded Jave/Android and Eclipse.

I have a test Android tablet (Viewsonic Viewpad 10s) which I will be running the software on.

I was hoping to be able to just plug the Android device straight into my PC to allow me to debug/run applications on the tablet.

I have purchased a male->male USB cable and plugged it into both devices, but nothing happens, it doesn't even come up with an 'unknown device' in the 'devices' window. Is there something else I need to be doing to get Windows to recognise this device? (I'm running Windows 7 (64bit)).

Alternatively, is this the best way to be running/debugging on the tablet? I was thinking that there might be a network debugging application, as both devices are on the network?

I'm totally new to Android, so might be missing something obvious. Although I have set the 'USB Debugging' within the 'Development' menu.

Thanks in advance.

Rich.

Answer (score 0):

It's a Windows problem, Windows isn't capable of recognize your tablet on its own, you need to install the appropriate USB drivers for your device in order to use your tablet when it is connected to your PC.

Under a GNU/linux distribution like Ubuntu everything is much more easier and you can just plug in your device without installing anything, you just have to set the right permissions for the device once.

Answer (score 0):

1. Unplug the device from your machine
2. Install the driver for your device : http://www.viewsonic.com/support/downloads/drivers/_download/tablet/viewpad10s/ViewPad_10s_USB_driver.zip
3. Plug your device in
4. look at the device for a notificaiton saying debugging enabled.

If you dont,  you will need to open Device Manager, find the listing that your computer thinks the device is and right click and uninstall it.  Then unplug and replug.

Comment: At the moment, in device manager, it doesn't show anything at all When I plug the device in, windows doesn't bat an eyelid.. do you think that installing the above drivers, Windows will spot it?

Comment: hmm.. could it be that I'm running Windows 7 64bit ? when I search for the drivers you're linking to above, it only lists drivers for x86.